# snowflake is creating table even with invalid warehouse name

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am using snowflake jdbc, and trying to create a table in snowflake by passing an invalid warehouse name and its still creating the table in default warehouse.

```
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:snowflake://<identifier>.snowflakecomputing.com?warehouse=invalid_warehouse&db=db&schema=schema&role=role";
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement st = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, "username", "password");
            st = conn.createStatement();
            
            ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("create table test_table_err (name varchar(32))");
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below, it's important to note that tables are not created IN a warehouse.  A warehouse is just the compute used to process queries.

Answer (score 3):

Create table like any other metadata-only operations in Snowflake does NOT need a warehouse to execute.

To verify if a warehouse was used in a query, you can go to the Query History and look for CLUSTER_NUMBER or SIZE (warehouse size), if these are empty/null, it means that the warehouse was not used.

[image]

Try running SELECT that returns some data and see if the default warehouse will still be used

Comment: To extend not every `create table` statement is metadata only operation, for instance `CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT 1 AS col1` requires compute.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is 1 more way to validate:

Use warehouse <warehouse_name>